# jquery autocomplete not working not using the same HTML on second div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have added an `autocomplete` to a `div`, which is working perfect. However, on click of a button, I am copying the HTML of this div to another div, Everything works fine except that **autocomplete in second div is not working at all**. My code is:

div1:

```
<div id="opt1">
    <form method="post" action="result-page.php">
        <input type="hidden" id="occasion" name="occasion">
        <div class="float-band">
            <img src="images/common/close-btn.png" alt="Close" class="close" onClick="$(this).parent().parent().parent().slideUp(300);" />
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input name="area" id="area" type="text" placeholder="Search Area, Location of your choice" autocomplete="off">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="text" name="CapacityList" placeholder="Guests Expected (approx.)" required>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <select name="BudgetPerPerson">
                            <option selected>Budget (per person)</option>
                            <option value="0-249">Less than Rs.250</option>
                            <option value="250-499">Rs.250 &lt; Rs.500</option>
                            <option value="500-749">Rs.500 &lt; Rs.750</option>
                            <option value="750-999">Rs.750 &lt; Rs.1000</option>
                            <option value="1000-1499">Rs.1000 &lt; Rs.1500</option>
                            <option value="1500-1999">Rs.1500 &lt; Rs.2000</option>
                            <option value="2000-N">Rs.2000 &amp; above</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input name="Search" type="submit" value="Search">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

HTML Copy code on click of button:

```
$("#img2").on('click', function() {
    $('#occasion').val('BirthdayParty');
    $("#opt2").slideDown(300);
    $('#opt1,#opt3,#opt4,#opt5').hide();

    $('#opt2').html($('#opt1').html());

    $('#occasion').val('BirthdayParty');
    $("#opt1,#opt3,#opt4,#opt5,#opt6").fadeOut();
});
```

Autocomplete initialize button written in `$(function)` :

```
$('#area').autocomplete({
    source: 'fetch.php/arealist',
    select: function(event, ui) {

        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("z-index: " + $(".selector").zIndex());
        $("#area").val(ui.item.label);
        //window.location.href = "detail.php?"+ui.item.value;
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {

        $("#area").val(ui.item.label);
        //this.value = ui.item.label;
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default focus behavior.
    }
});
```

I have tried `destroy/disable/setting autocomplete to null` but nothing has worked till now. Any idea where am I missing ?

Comment: Are you changing the id of the element when you are copying the HTML?

Comment: @Sanjeevi.V no I am not changing the ID

Comment: if you not changing the id is this an issue of duplicated id? @Satya

Comment: ID needs to be unique for the document, please refer [link](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really). After making it unique, try adding the autocomplete handler dynamically, normally for dynamic handler we will be using common factors such as class name or just the name attribute.

Comment: @pekka, even if the ID is changed the element is being added after the DOM load. hence the event needs to be bounded again or we can use something like jquery on function if available.

Comment: @Sanjeevi.V can he not use event delegation for dynamically created element?

Comment: @pekka, Yes, there are various flavors of doing it. We can use which ever method we want. But we need to check the autocomplete API for what is supported.

Comment: Thanks a lot gentlemen, it was a pleasure listening to you. I fixed the problem by replacing the id , and then dynamically calling autocomplete. Sanjeevi/Pekka, thanks a lot for reminding me of duplicate id.

Comment: @Satya?can you post the answer and accept it for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by

```
1) copied the HTML of div1 to a String
2) replaced the id of Autocomplete with a new one in the String
3) set the target div HTML to the new String
4) initialized the new Autocomplete 

k = $('#opt1').html();
k = k.replace(/area/g,'areab');
$('#opt2').html(k);
$('#areab').attr('name', 'area');
 $('#areab').autocomplete({
    source: 'fetch.php/arealist',
    select: function(event, ui) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $("#areab").val(ui.item.label);
     },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
     $("#areab").val(ui.item.label);
     event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default focus behavior.
    }
});
```

Special thanks to @Sanjeevi and @Pekka